# Is it possible to use the Remote Photography feature of Snapbridge to control my Nikon 3400D with an iPhone?

Tags: remote, snapbridge, nikon-d3400

Is there any way to use the "Remote Photography" feature of Nikon's Snapbridge app to control my D3400 with my iPhone?

I tried, but it only allows me to download pics from the D3400.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SnapBridge version 2.5 (and up), allows for Remote Control over Bluetooth (in addition to remote control over WiFi). E.g., D3500 doesn't have WiFi either but Remote Control is possible with SnapBridge (https://nikonimglib.com/snbr/onlinehelp/en/05_remote_02.html). HOWEVER, for reasons only known to Nikon, it doesn't make the same available for D3400 (I guess it's b/c D3400 is an older product, they don't want to invest the resource needed to update the firmware for this function).

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. The D3400 does not have wifi, which is required for Snapbridge-enabled cameras to be controlled by the remote smart device.

From [Nikon Europe's product page for the D3400](https://www.europe-nikon.com/en_GB/product/digital-cameras/slr/consumer/d3400)

> The D3400 makes it spectacularly easy to shoot and share DSLR-quality images. Nikon’s SnapBridge¹ keeps the camera connected to your smart device via Bluetooth® so you can actually sync photos as you shoot.
>
> ...
>
> ¹ *As the D3400 does not support Wi-Fi, **the following SnapBridge features are not available: remote photography with a smart device**, still image transfer in original size, movie transfer.*

Aside: Interesting (rather, *annoying*) that I couldn't find the same clear information on Nikon USA's site.

Comment: Nikon seems to always plays hide-and-seek with their lower tiered cameras lack of features/support in articles that are about the feature/software/lens.

Comment: I don't know why Nikon can't implement remote shutter over Blue Tooth but I digress...

Comment: @TheXed It has nothing to do with _can't_. It's simply _won't_, as in they do not have the _will_ to do so. Frustrating, to say the least...

Comment: @scottbb fair enough.